Change the language of cardtext in Microsoft Word
I have a problem with Cardtext, I want it to convert numbers to words in Arabic but it shows in English and no matter what I do it won't change

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The issue with CardText converting numbers to words in English instead of Arabic can be resolved with these steps:
Change Document Language to Arabic:
    Go to Review > Language > Set Proofing Language and select Arabic. Set it as default.

Ensure Arabic is Installed:
    Go to File > Options > Language, and make sure Arabic is installed and set as default for display and proofing.

Use VBA (Macro) for Arabic Conversion:
    Since CardText doesn't support Arabic, you'll need a custom VBA script to convert numbers to Arabic words.

This should help with your issue!
